# Evaluate Dendrogram Statistical Significance

Tags: python, clustering, scipy, confidence, bootstraping

I have N=21 objects and each one has about 80 possible not NaN descriptors.
I carried out a hierarchical clustering on the objects and I obtained this dendrogram.
[image]
I want some kind of 'confidence' index for the dendrogram or for each node. I saw many dendrograms with Bootstrap values (as far as I understand it is the same as Monte Carlo Cross-Validation, but I might be wrong), and i think that in my case they could be used as well.
I'm currently using scipy.hierarchy python package with Ward (and also Average Linkage) method.
Do you know any python package that could do this kind of analysis?